# Quotient spaces of homeomorphic spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

Let's take $X$ be a regular connected space, and take $Y$ to be a connected regular subspace such that $X \cong Y$.

Is it true that $X/Y$ (we identify the elements of $Y$ as a point) homehomorphic to $X$ or to a point?

If my proposition is false, what can we say about such quotient spaces? If there exists a reference it also would be nice.

BTW: We can take general (or even more concrete spaces). I'm looking for interesting results (a classification of such spaces, for example).

For example, if we take $ X = \mathbb{R}$, and $ Y = (a,b) $ than we get: $ X/X \cong \{e\} $ and $ X/Y \cong X $.

**Update**: According to the comments the $ \mathbb{R} / (a,b) \not \cong \mathbb{R}$ so my example actually **disproves** the conjenture.

Comment: $\mathbb R/(a,b)$ isn't homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.  It isn't even Hausdorff.

Comment: We can get many different results. For example, if $X$ is countably many disjoint copies of $Z$, then $X/Y$ can be 42 disjoint copies of $Z$ plus a point

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Noticed the hypothesis "connected"

Comment: @Aweygan thanks for your currection, I'll fix it.

Comment: @user281392 OK, then take the cone of my space and there's still a lot of different results to get. -- More genreally: Let $Z$ be any connected space, $z_0\in Z$ a closed point. Let $X$ consist of countably many copies of $Z$, glued together at their $z_0$'s. If $Y$ is obtained by leaving out one of the copies of $Z$, then $X\cong Y$, and $X/Y\cong Z$.

Comment: @Aweygan just to clarify, is $\mathbb{R} /(a,b)$ not Hausdorff because $a$ and $b$ are distinct but there are no open sets separating them?

Comment: @OsamaGhani Yes, any open set containing either $a$ or $b$ also contains the point that $(a,b)$ was collapsed to.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be the annulus $S^1\times [0,1]$ and $Y$ the homeomorphic subspace $S^1\times[0,1/2]$. The quotient $X/Y$ is homeomorphic to a disk.